# Does device token change after update iOS OS to newer version?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Few of my device have stopped receiving push notification after updating the device to newer iOS version.
So, My question is, Does device token change after update iOS OS to newer version? and I need to update my device token on my server too.

Answer (score 2):

Apple Documentation says that we should generate device token every time application launches.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {}
```

This method get called everytime when application launches and here you need to send device token to server. So it doesn't matter if token changes or not. Apple Push notification server will be aware of new token and should send notification to right device .

And you should never use device token for some kind of device identification.

This is what [original documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns) says :

**Important:
Never cache device tokens in local storage. APNs issues a new token when the user restores a device from a backup, when the user installs your app on a new device, and when the user reinstalls the operating system. If you ask the system to provide the token each time, you’re guaranteed to get an up-to-date token.**

Comment: thanks @Vikas, I have one last doubt. If I update my iOS version from 15 to ios 16. Is there are change that The Device token will also updated.
I have added code to update device token on server in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken function of app delegate

Comment: No , the device token doesn't change if you update device IOS version. Atleast, Apple documentation doesn't suggest that it changes.